# SQL query with SUM, ORDER BY, with limited values

Tags: t-sql

I am having a troubles to get expected result.

I have successfully joined 2 tables (database is SQL Server), however I would like to have something more.

Excel - it's table which contains list of `PartNumbers(GBC)` with corresponding `Quantity` of this part needed for build.

I'm joining this Excel with my `Inventory` database to retrieve information about what I have, what is missing, what I need to purchase.

Current query:

```
string sqlCheck = @"SELECT e.GBC, e.Replaced, e.Description, Barcode, Location, Bookstand, Quantity, Buildneed, p.Quantity - e.Buildneed as Afterbuild FROM Parts p Right JOIN Excel e ON e.GBC = p.GBC ORDER BY GBC ASC, Quantity DESC";
```

Results as below image:

[image]

It is needed to use ALL duplicated `GBC` but in specific order.

First I need to take `GBC(86911)` with `Quantity = 100`, this should result in `Afterbuild = 0`.

But in column `Buildneed` I see that I need 768 in total, so next step would be to take `GBC(86911)` with `quantity = 500`, this should result in `Afterbuild 0`, and in this line I would like to see new column called `Totals` which will be equal to -168 (which will mean I need to buy 168 pcs of this part).

1. I can have many same parts with different quantities
2. I always want to start from lowest quantity on particular duplicated `GBC`
3. This should not show me more `GBC` if `Buildneed` value will be exceeded

Expected output as on below image:

I have added column 'UseInOrder' - **it is not neccessery** but would be awesome if its possible also, it will point me that I will need to use all parts from each in that order.

[image]

As suggested, below table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Excel] (
    [GBC]         INT          NULL,
    [Description] VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [Buildneed]   INT          NULL,
    [Replaced]    VARCHAR (50) NULL
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Parts] (
    [Barcode]       INT          IDENTITY (201900001, 1) NOT NULL,
    [GBC]           INT          NULL,
    [Description]   VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [Location]      VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [Bookstand]     VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [Value]         VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [Quantity]      INT          NULL,
    [MQuantity]     INT          NULL,
    [Manufacturer1] VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [MPN1]          VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [Manufacturer2] VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [MPN2]          VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [Manufacturer3] VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [MPN3]          VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Parts] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Barcode] ASC)
);
```

**EDIT** Sample data

```
declare @tblParts table(
  GBC int,
  Barcode varchar(256),
  [Location] varchar(256),
  Quantity int
)

declare @tblPartsUsed table(
  GBC int,
  Replaced varchar(1) default '',
  [Description] varchar(50),
  Buildneed int
)

insert into @tblParts (GBC,[Description], Barcode, [Location], Quantity)
select 86911, 'CAP_CER,10nF,0603,10%,100V,X7R' ,201901200, 'JD-01/  14' ,500
union all
select 86911, 'CAP_CER,10nF,0603,10%,100V,X7R' ,201901166, 'ESB-03' ,100
union all
select 99529, 'DIO_ZENR,5,6V,2%,MM3Z5V6ST1G,SOD323' ,201901024, 'ESB-01' ,100
union all
select 128082, 'CAP_CER,100nF,0603,10%,50V,X7R, poly' ,201901120, 'JD-01/  3' ,500
union all
select 128082, 'CAP_CER,100nF,0603,10%,50V,X7R, poly' ,201901121, 'JD-01/  3' ,500
union all
select 168078, 'CAP_CER,470nF,0805,10%,50V,X7R' ,201901207, 'JD-01/  19' ,170
union all
select 168078, 'CAP_CER,470nF,0805,10%,50V,X7R' ,201901152, 'ESB-03' ,140
union all
select 196881, 'BJT,C,SMBT3946DW1T1G,SOT363' ,201901085, 'ESB-02' ,100
union all
select 199296, 'BJT_DIG,C,SMUN5311DW1T1G,SOT363' ,201901083, 'ESB-02' ,100
union all
select 207735, 'DIO_LED, NFSA123DT' ,201902132, 'KRK' ,10


insert into @tblPartsUsed(GBC, [Description], Buildneed)
select 71744, 'RES_TF,10k,0402,1%,0,1W,100PPM/C' ,192
union all
select 71746, 'RES_TF,10k,0603,1%,0,1W,100PPM/C' ,168
union all
select 76527, 'CAP_CER,10nF,0402,10%,50V,X7R' ,288
union all
select 86911, 'CAP_CER,10nF,0603,10%,100V,X7R' ,1464
union all
select 92854, 'RES_TF,30k,0603,1%,0,1W,100PPM/C' ,72
union all
select 93018, 'RES_TF,68k,0603,1%,0,1W,100PPM/C' ,72
union all
select 95241, 'RES_TF,2k2,0402,1%,0,1W,100PPM/C' ,192
union all
select 95549, 'RES_TF,47k,0603,1%,0,1W,100PPM/C' ,72
union all
select 99529, 'DIO_ZENR,5,6V,2%,MM3Z5V6ST1G,SOD323' ,72
union all
select 112117, 'RES_TF,2k2,0603,1%,0,1W,100PPM/C' ,96
union all
select 126486, 'RES_TF,0R,0603' ,24
union all
select 128082, 'CAP_CER,100nF,0603,10%,50V,X7R, poly' ,72
union all
select 168078, 'CAP_CER,470nF,0805,10%,50V,X7R' ,72
union all
select 196200, 'BJT_DIG,N,PDTC114EU,SOT323' ,72
union all
select 196881, 'BJT,C,SMBT3946DW1T1G,SOT363' ,144
union all
select 199296, 'BJT_DIG,C,SMUN5311DW1T1G,SOT363' ,504
union all
select 199302, 'RES_TF,100R,0603,10%,0,1W,200PPM/C' ,72
union all
select 202047, 'UNI,N,PMPB215ENEA,DFN2020MD-6' ,72
union all
select 202054, 'DIO_LED,SPMWHT346EA3' ,648
union all
select 203509, 'CONN_HEADER,MOLEX,5023521100' ,24
union all
select 207735, 'DIO_LED, NFSA123DT' ,648
union all
select 207843, 'Thermistor,10k,0603,1%,NTC' ,24
union all
select 208252, 'FOOTPRINT_BOARD-IN,MOLEX,350220011' ,48
union all
select 212145, 'DIO_SIGN,200V,250mA,50nS,BAV21WSQ-7-F,SOD323' ,72
```

Based on this date, output should be like on below image of table:

[image]

Comment: please, show result table that you expect

Comment: @RomaRuzich Added to question, thank You for pointing out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

**EDIT2** (after change initial data)

```
SELECT distinct u.GBC,p2.Replaced, p2.Description, IIF(u.Afterbuild>0, MIN(p1.Barcode) OVER(PARTITION BY u.GBC), p1.Barcode) as Barcode, p1.Location, u.Quantity, u.Buildneed, 
CASE
  when (u.Total <0 AND p1.Barcode is NULL) OR (SUM(u.Quantity) OVER(PARTITION BY u.GBC) - u.Buildneed)>0 then u.Afterbuild
  else 0
end
as Afterbuild,
CASE
   when u.Total <0 AND p1.Barcode is NULL then ABS(u.Total)
   when (SUM(u.Quantity) OVER(PARTITION BY u.GBC) - u.Buildneed)>0 then u.Total
   else u.Total
END as Total FROM
(
    SELECT distinct b.GBC, b.Quantity, b.Buildneed, 
       case 
           when b.Total <0 then null
           when b.Total >=0 AND MIN(b.Quantity) OVER(PARTITION BY b.GBC) - b.Buildneed < 0 AND b.Quantity = MAX(b.Quantity) OVER(PARTITION BY b.GBC) then SUM(b.Quantity) OVER(PARTITION BY b.GBC) - b.Buildneed
           when b.Total >=0 AND MIN(b.Quantity) OVER(PARTITION BY b.GBC) - b.Buildneed >= 0 AND b.Quantity = MIN(b.Quantity) OVER(PARTITION BY b.GBC) then MIN(b.Quantity) OVER(PARTITION BY b.GBC) - b.Buildneed
       END AS Afterbuild,
       case 
           when b.Total >=0 then null
           when b.Total <0 AND b.RowNumber = MAX(b.RowNumber) OVER(PARTITION BY b.GBC) then b.Total 
       END AS Total
    FROM
    (
        select r.GBC, r.Quantity, r.Buildneed,
        (SUM(r.Quantity) OVER(PARTITION BY r.GBC)) - r.Buildneed as Total, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by r.GBC, r.Quantity) as RowNumber
        from 
        (
            SELECT e.GBC, ISNULL(Quantity,0) as Quantity, ISNULL(Buildneed,0) as Buildneed FROM @tblParts p RIGHT JOIN @tblPartsUsed e ON e.GBC = p.GBC
        ) as r
    ) as b
) as u 
left join @tblParts as p1 on u.GBC = p1.GBC and ISNULL(u.Quantity,0) = ISNULL(p1.Quantity,0)
left join @tblPartsUsed as p2 on u.GBC = p2.GBC and ISNULL(u.Buildneed,0) = ISNULL(p2.Buildneed,0)
where (u.Afterbuild is not null or u.Total is not null or u.Quantity - u.Buildneed < 0)
order by u.GBC, u.Quantity
```

Comment: I'm sorry its still not working as expected please check current output under this link [reslut_table](https://imgur.com/a/xYuYnlv) case when Quantity > Buildneed, should be equal in After build as Quantity - Buildneed, and next available same part should not appear in table

Comment: I edit answer. If it is not correct for your then show example of data in each of table and result that you expect for this data.

Comment: I've added sample data, with expected output with description of possible cases, please make a note that in tblParts there is no possible to have parts without barcode, this table is created during creation stock with parts. tblPartsUsed is just list of parts needed for build, thats why i have to join those 2 tables to see what i have on stock(tableParts), what i need to manage for build, or what is not enough. Thank You very much for Your attention

Comment: Why do you subtract 72 from 140 but no 170 for GBC = 168078?

Comment: Imagine You have 2x same butter with different weight, to make sandwich You want to use butter with less weigh just to cover sandwich and throw away package from butter, this is similar :-)

Comment: To be honest, i have joined both answers to get expected output, and that "Case 4." is last thing i need, just to see as many items as needed to cover Buildneed, would You like to help me on chat ? I will paste You current querry

Comment: I change query. Try again)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200887/discussion-between-kuba-do-and-roma-ruzich).

Comment: Hello Roma, there is one more Case (5).. imgbbb.com/image/LVqP8F - See line 14, after build should be equal to 1 :( please check

Comment: changed query. try

Comment: Please set both Quantity to 30, 30- You will see following problem. With Total value --> [link](https://ibb.co/5Ryvw5r),, It work OK when one item is more then needed as sum, all other cases also OK now !

Comment: Well its not part of my job to do it, or even task to acomplish - im doing it to learn, with working example I can study how its working.. Sorry for bothering You its still not working, it has duplicated those rows [image](https://ibb.co/MB5zBYX) it happen only when all items have same values, and sum is less then buildneed

Answer (score 2):

As per @RomaRuzich this question needs expected results in a table format.

Also the Parts and Excel table structure is needed with some data to clarify the question.

Made some assumptions and created script with output results.

```
declare @tblParts table(
                        GBC int, 
                        Barcode varchar(20), 
                        [Location] varchar(20), 
                        Bookstand varchar(10) default '',
                        Quantity int
                        )
```

```
declare @tblPartsUsed table(
                        GBC int, 
                        Replaced varchar(1) default '', 
                        [Description] varchar(50), 
                        Buildneed int
                        )

insert into @tblParts(GBC, Barcode, [Location], Quantity)
select 72223, '', '', 0
union all
select 86911, '201901200','JD-01/',500
union all
select 86911, '201901166','JD-01/ 14', 100

insert into @tblPartsUsed(GBC, [Description],  Buildneed)
select '72223', 'RES_TF', 60
union all
select '86911', 'CAP_CER, 10nf,0603', 768
union all
select '86911', 'CAP_CER, 10nf,0603', 768
```

```
SELECT distinct e.GBC, e.Replaced, e.[Description], Barcode, [Location],
 Bookstand, Quantity, Buildneed,
 p.Quantity - e.Buildneed as Afterbuild,
 x.TotalQuantity - Buildneed as Totals
FROM @tblParts p Right JOIN @tblPartsUsed e ON e.GBC = p.GBC 
    left join (select GBC, sum(Quantity) TotalQuantity from @tblParts group by GBC) x <br/>on e.GBC = x.GBC
ORDER BY e.GBC ASC, p.Quantity ASC
```

[image]

Comment: This is very close to what i need, i will add (hope so in table format expected result) to question, thank You in advance for Your effort